# com.intellij.javaee.oss.admin.jmx.JmxAdminException: com.intellij.execution.ExecutionException

Tags: java, intellij-idea, artifact

When I run tomcat in IntelliJ IDEA, I get this below error, I have searched the StackOverflow, find nothing about my exception.

> [2017-04-06 10:57:30,875] Artifact elecMaven-explored: Artifact is being deployed, please wait...
>   [2017-04-06 10:57:30,888] Artifact elecMaven-explored: Error during artifact deployment. See server log for details.
>   [2017-04-06 10:57:30,889] Artifact elecMaven-explored: com.intellij.javaee.oss.admin.jmx.JmxAdminException: com.intellij.execution.ExecutionException: /Users/luowensheng/Desktop/TestIOS/itheima1128elecMaven/classes/artifacts/elecMaven_explored not found for the web module.

But my artifact is really exists:

[image]

So, where is the issue?

---

I have tried:

add the below code to web.xml:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>kmRootKey</param-name>
    <param-value>km.root</param-value>
</context-param>
```

But seems useless.

Comment: Please share the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 17):

The issue maybe you did not create the correct Artifact.
The correct steps are:

When you create the Artifact, you should like this:

[image]

If you in the step3 choose the Empty, you maybe will get the error of title.

Then in Tomcat Configurations, you can deploy the Artifact like this:

[image]

And check it:
[image]

Restart your Tomcat.

Comment: I closed IntelliJ Idea then re-imported the project and choose as artifact war-exploded by following above step. And the issue is resolved.

Comment: I'm pleased this can help you.

Comment: This solved my problem as well. Somehow during clean up for project directories the tomcat server configuration had removed building the artifact during server startup. I had to enable it using the edit feature and the server started deploying the correct war file during startup.

Comment: I do not have a secondary menu attached to the *Web Application: Exploded* item.

Answer (score 8):

Select your artifact (*File -> Project Structure -> Artifacts*) and make sure **Output directory** points to correct directory (for example, *path_to_webapp\target*).

That's how I solved this problem.

Comment: This is a good answer that worked for me. For some reason Intellij tries to look in an `/out` folder that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 5):

**I also suffered with this issue...** *This occurs because*

Tomcat doesn't find your project folder(application folder) to deploy. So

- Click on "Edit configuration" button, top right in intellij
- Configure Tomcat by clicking '**+**' symbol on left top and selecting "**Tomcat server**" then **local**.
- Give "**Name**" to your project as per need.
- Now in first tab "**Server**"...
- Set path to local tomcat directory in your system.
- Better change "Http port" 8080 to 808* (8086, 8087, 8088...)
- Go to second tab "**Deployment**"
- Under "Deploy at the server startup" Click on **+** symbol and select **artifact**. Now artifact having *same name as your project-name* should be listed in it.
  Then click OK

**And unfortunately if above steps aren't helpful**

- Go to the **Deployment** tab, click on edit button(pencil). It will open a new window called
  "Project Structure".
- Give "Name" and specify "Type" as **Web Application: Exploded**
- Under **Output directory** give the location of your project folder like
  (D:\Workspace\Project_Folder).

Answer (score 4):

Re-importing maven projects resolved the issue for me

Comment: "Open the "Maven Projects" tab/window and clicking the "Reimport All Maven Projects" in the upper left corner" - this is how to actually do this answer

Answer (score 2):

I faced with the same problem. In my case, it was a flag  in Gradle's settings. I switched it on and forgot to set it back to off:

[image: flag]

To check it go to **"Build, Execution, Deployment" -> "Build Tools" -> "Gradle" -> "Runner"**. The flag "**Delegate IDE build/run actions to gradle**" must be unchecked.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I've resolved this problem by manually created folders in project root "out/artifacts/artifactName"

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).