# How to fix module not found: spring.web and similar errors

Tags: java, spring, maven, module-path

I'm trying to build a simple maven spring-rest app with Java 11, but I'm getting 'module not found error' constantly.

I read a lot of similar questions on SO. I tried various recommendations - deletions of maven repository, resolving some warnings etc., but I still can't make the project work.

My parrent pom:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

   <groupId>com.luv2code</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-rest-demo</artifactId>
   <version>1.0</version>
    <modules>
        <module>nedim</module>
    </modules>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

   <properties>
      <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
      <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
      <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
   </properties>

   <dependencies>

      <!-- Add Spring MVC and REST support -->
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
         <version>5.0.5.RELEASE</version>
      </dependency>

      <!-- Add Jackson for JSON converters -->
      <dependency>
         <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
         <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
         <version>2.9.5</version>
      </dependency>

      <!-- Add Servlet support for 
          Spring's AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer -->
      <dependency>
         <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
         <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
         <version>3.1.0</version>
      </dependency>
   </dependencies>

   <!-- Support for Maven WAR Plugin -->

   <build>

      <finalName>spring-rest-demo</finalName>

      <pluginManagement>
         <plugins><plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>               
            </plugin>                 
         </plugins>
      </pluginManagement>
   </build>

</project>
```

Child pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>spring-rest-demo</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.luv2code</groupId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>nedim</artifactId>


</project>
```

module-info.java:

```
open module nedim {
    requires spring.context;
    requires spring.webmvc;
    requires spring.web; 
}
```

When I run maven clean install, I get the following:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project nedim: Compilation failure: Compilation failure: 
[ERROR] /D:/Workspace/Java/spring-rest-demo/nedim/src/main/java/module-info.java:[2,24] module not found: spring.context
[ERROR] /D:/Workspace/Java/spring-rest-demo/nedim/src/main/java/module-info.java:[3,24] module not found: spring.webmvc
[ERROR] /D:/Workspace/Java/spring-rest-demo/nedim/src/main/java/module-info.java:[4,24] module not found: spring.web
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :nedim
```

Also, I added to VM options `--show-module-resolution` and there is no spring modules on list

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The main problem is: `org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile`. This is a very old version that doesn't support JPMS. Please update to 3.8.1

Comment: Thanks, Robert! Actually, a half-hour ago I found your answer to a slightly different problem here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46939741/java-9-automatic-module-dependencies-cannot-be-resolved-module-not-found and it solved my problem. But now I have another problem: it seems like my Spring configurations and mapping in controllers (all in 'nedim' module - module names are just for testing) are not used during project initialization. Did I miss something? Shouldn't spring-container be initialized by now?

Comment: Sorry...  I just noticed the log: Artifact unnamed: com.intellij.javaee.oss.admin.jmx.JmxAdminException: com.intellij.execution.ExecutionException: D:\Workspace\Java\spring-rest-demo\out\artifacts\unnamed\unnamed.war not found for the web module. I'm not sure what that means, but apperently this is a problem.

Comment: And the solution is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43244946/com-intellij-javaee-oss-admin-jmx-jmxadminexception-com-intellij-execution-exec/43251205 I'm making this record as a possible reference for someone with same problem.